# cannot download files with spanish accents (áéíóú) from moodle, goes to a 403 error, but the accents are displayed correctly in the pages

Tags: php, mysql, apache, centos, moodle

cannot download files with spanish accents (áéíóú) from moodle, goes to a 403 error, but the accents are displayed correctly in the pages.
I'm using a Moodle 2.4.3 and a CentOS 6.5 with mysql and apache

I have already tried:

```
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and

```
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=ISO-8859-1
AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
```

but nothing changed.

if (you have an idea about how to solve this) thanks;
else thanks too;

Comment: I'm guessing there is a bug before the download starts which causes it to fail. Try switching on debugging level to develop and display all errors - site admin -> development -> debugging

Comment: it's already on developer debug level and the error_log shows nothing relevant, I made a fail login before try to download the file and just the fail login error appeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, found the answer, in the mod_rewrite in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf rewrites the URLs to show more beautifull, I just comment the line that turns it on:

#  RewriteEngine On

now my URLs are ugly, I don't care and works.

thanks Russell England and everyone who looked for an answer.